# Push data to apps from MySql

Tags: networking, mysql, synchronization

I just stumbled over [RethinkDB](http://rethinkdb.com/) and I like the sound of it:

> RethinkDB pushes JSON to your apps in realtime.
>
> When your app polls for data, it becomes slow, unscalable, and
>   cumbersome to maintain.
>
> RethinkDB is the open-source, scalable database that makes building
>   realtime apps dramatically easier.

This sounds great for a multi-user system. Until now, I have been had the client apps polling the DB server - almost certainly far too frequently, in an attempt to stop collisions.

Ok, collisions can still happen with this model; one user updates a record as another deletes it. But the bandwidth savings sound very attractive.

**Does anyone know of something similar which can sit in front of a MySql database?**